# Index was out of range

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Can somebody help with this snippet of code which has an exception. It always stacks on [2,0] index. I just can't figure out how to solve this. I have added a screenshot below.

```
private Matrix GridToMatrix(DataGridView grid)
{
    var matrix = new double[grid.RowCount, grid.ColumnCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            matrix[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(grid[i, j].Value);
        }
    }

    return new Matrix(matrix);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `grid[i, j]` to `grid[j, i]`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov you are correct, but add an answer explaining the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the [confusing indexing mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158656(v=vs.110).aspx) of `DataGridView`.

The indexing for `DataGridView` is like `[col, row]` while Matrix indexing is `[row, col]`

By changing `grid[i, j]` to `grid[j, i]` the problem will resolve.